# React - jest Use custom state to check conditions in component

Tags: reactjs, redux, jestjs, enzyme

I want to use different state values to check if else part in a function - react unit testing
So i can get full coverage[click here to view code-left- testing code right- function to check]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Ciao, accroding to what I know, you could get the full coverage by setting state with setState (as you already do in your test) and then re-call `componentInstance.handleLogin(event)`. Something like:

```
const event = { preventDefault: jest.fn };
wrapper.setState({username: "user", password: "pass"});  // this should cover if(username && password)
componentInstance.handleLogin(event);
expect(...)
wrapper.setState({username: "user", password: undefined}); // this should cover if(username && !password)
componentInstance.handleLogin(event);
expect(...)
wrapper.setState({username: undefined, password: "pass"}); // this should cover if(!username && password)
componentInstance.handleLogin(event);
expect(...)
wrapper.setState({username: undefined, password: undefined}); // this should cover if(!username && !password)
componentInstance.handleLogin(event);
expect(...)
```

Between calls you could `expect` something maybe related to the code inside if statements. I think this should give you full coverage.

Comment: As i said earlier i have set the state but its not reflected, it always considers the state mentioned in components constructor

Answer (score 0):

```
it('handleLogin with different conditions', () => {
    const handleLogin = jest.fn();
    const event = { preventDefault: jest.fn() };
    const wrapper = mount(
        <MemoryRouter
            initialEntries={[{ pathname: '/', key: 'testKey', state: {} }]}
        >
            <Provider store={store}>
                <Login handleLogin={handleLogin} />
            </Provider>
        </MemoryRouter>
    );
    const componentInstance = wrapper.find('Login').instance();
    componentInstance.setState({ username: "user", password: "pass" });
    componentInstance.handleLogin(event);

    componentInstance.setState({ username: "user", password: "" });
    componentInstance.handleLogin(event);

    componentInstance.setState({ username: "", password: "pass" });
    componentInstance.handleLogin(event);
})
```